# how to stop auto play in telegram?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I've developed a Telegram bot. the bot sends some audio files Continuously. hence, when I play the last audio file, the previous audio files before the last audio file will be played automatically. how can I disable autoplay in telegram? I want to play each audio file based on user selection.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. How did you solve it?

Comment: Sadly this is currently impossible. What you can do is make sure to have only 1 "active" voice message in the chat, by always deleting the previous one. It's a little messy, but it works.